# No JRE included in app when using fx:deploy through Ant

Tags: java, ant, javafx, packager

I'm trying to use javafxpackager and Ant to create a self-contained application (preferrably as an msi, but same results with exe).

If I run the javafxpackager from the command-line, it works perfectly.

If I run it through Ant (using fx:deploy), it still runs to completion, but when I install the application, it does NOT include the 'jre' directory.

When I install, then run, I get the following message:

```
Error loading jvm.dll
```

How do I get Ant, using fx:deploy, to include the JRE directory in my application package?

Comment: How is attribute nativeBundles set ? Did you use nativeBundles="all" ?

Comment: Can you post the `build.xml` or the code for `<fx:deploy>` ?

Comment: This [JavaFX deployment blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7) notes: "Self-Contained Applications: Create Package without Java Runtime . . . Pass empty string as value for '`basedir`' attribute and this will be treated as request to not bundle Java runtime, e.g.
`<fx:platform basedir=""/>`".  Is this what you are doing?